# IIS website host multiple Angular applications

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, web-hosting

I want to host multiple independent angular applications on single IIS virtual directory

**For example**:

- mysite.com/admin
- mysite.com/sales
- mysite.com/inventory

If I host with folders then URLs to inner pages won't work

For example:

- mysite.com/admin--- Working
- mysite.com/admin/home --- Not working

Comment: Yes it is doable. Just deploy each app to respective folders.

Comment: In iis do I need to add route config with iis routing module to target index page?

Answer (score 3):

you just need to do below things:

set the base href in the index.file:

[image]

```
 <base href="/app3/">
```

another is set the script link like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./runtime.js"></script>
```

you just need to add ./

so your whole code will look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularApp2</title>
  <base href="/app3/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<h2>app3</h2>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./es2015-polyfills.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

and when you host angular application iis do not forget to set dist folder as a folder path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jalpa, i have tried this but URL routing won't work. For example if I hit localhost/app3/home won't work but localhost/app3/ will work

Comment: could you share your URL routing? for the URL rewrite routing rule issue, you could run [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) and check what is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the assumptions of **Ajay Nikam**, who wants to host multiple independent Angular applications under virtual hosts within a single IIS site.

- example.com/admin
- example.com/sales
- example.com/inventory

For each of the folders *admin*, *sales*, and *inventory*, create a **web.config** file with the following content :

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Redirect HTTP request to HTTPS -->
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <!-- Avoid 404 error when refreshing web application -->
        <rule name="Angular Catch All" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For each of the folders *admin*, *sales*, and *inventory*, adjust the "href" attribute value of the  tag in the **index.html** file as follows (for automating this adjustment, see the TIP below) :

- For the *admin* folder :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example Admin</title>
        <base href="https://example.com/admin/">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

- For the *sales* folder :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example Sales</title>
        <base href="https://example.com/sales/">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

- For the *inventory* folder :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example Inventory</title>
        <base href="https://example.com/inventory/">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

TIP: To automate the "href" attribute of the "base" tag through the Angular project (**scripts.build** in the *package.json*) :

```json
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --base-href=https://example.com/admin/",
    ...
  }
}
```

Additionally, here's an example of routing from the **app-routing.module.ts** file of the Angular project related to *admin* :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './core/components/not-found/component/not-found.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './modules/home/component/home.component';



const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Finally, convert each *admin*, *sales*, and *inventory* folder into **IIS applications**.

After completing the above steps, there should be one IIS site and three IIS applications, each hosting a distinct Angular web application. Each application will respond to the URL [https://example.com/[admin|sales|inventory]](https://example.com/%5Badmin%7Csales%7Cinventory%5D).

The routing for each application will work correctly.